# How do I send an email based on a date difference?

Tags: trigger, email, formula, scheduled-apex, scheduled

For example, I have some `DateTimeField__c`, and if `DateTimeField__c - NOW() = 11` (hours), I should send an email. Trigger is not a variant, because I can't check with it a formula field. A Scheduled class is a bad variant too. I can't always run it: there is already a lot of logic with callouts and schedules. Can you advise something?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Workflow Rule` here, not `Apex`. Specifically, **[Add a Time-Dependent Action to Your Workflow Rule](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_time_dependent.htm&type=5)**:

> Time-dependent actions are executed at a specific time, such as 10 days before a record’s close date. When that specific time passes, the workflow rule re-evaluates the record to make sure that it still meets the rule criteria. If the record does, the workflow rule executes those actions.

Comment: I think it will not work with a lot of messages. Or it will? What are day's limits for it for, e. q., enterprise edition?